# Connector/J: MysqlDataSource.setConnectionTimeZone() doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, datasource, mysql-connector

[MySQL Connector/J 8.0.23 (2021-01-18) added 3 new connection properties](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/connector-j-8.0-relnotes-en/news-8-0-23.html): `connectionTimeZone`, `preserveInstants`, and `forceConnectionTimeZoneToSession`.

I have been creating the connection using:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + hostname
   + ":" + port
   + "/" + databaseName
   + "?user=" + username
   + "&password=" + password
   + "&preserveInstants=false"
   + "&connectionTimeZone=UTC"
   + "&serverTimeZone=UTC"
   + "&forceConnectionTimeZoneToSession=true";
```

I want to switch to using `MysqlDataSource`, and have gotten this far:

```
MysqlDataSource source = new MysqlDataSource();
source.setServerName(hostname);
source.setPort(port);
source.setDatabaseName(databaseName);
source.setUser(username);
source.getPassword(password);
source.setPreserveInstants(false);
source.???;   // Something like .setConnectionTimeZone() does not exist
source.setServerTimezone("UTC");
source.setForceConnectionTimeZoneToSession(true);
```

I don't see how to set `connectionTimeZone`, unless I skip setting everything individually and just use `source.setUrl(url)`.

There are no other `.setX` methods having to do with timezones, other than the 2 I'm already using, so it doesn't appear to just be named differently.

I'm using mysql-connector-java 8.0.27.  I do see 8.0.28 is released, but its release notes don't mention any changes for `MysqlDataSource`.

(For anyone who wonders, my goal is to have MySQL Connector/J always operate in UTC, period, and never touch any dates or times.)

Answer (score 0):

I may have figured out the answer.  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/connector-j-8.0-en/connector-j-time-instants.html mentions:

> Note

> For Connector/J 8.0.23 and later, serverTimezone is an alias for connectionTimeZone. For Connector/J 8.0.22 and earlier, serverTimezone was used to override the session time zone setting on the server.

That leads me to believe I was being redundant providing both (on 8.0.23+) `connectionTimeZone=UTC` and `serverTimeZone=UTC`, and the left the older `MysqlDataSource.setServerTimezone()` be without adding a new method for the same thing.

So, perhaps all I need to do is remove the `source.???;` line in my original post, since maybe `source.setServerTimezone("UTC");` covers it.